# C# find image within image with tolerance

Tags: c#, image, image-processing, bitmap

I have a function which will find a smaller image within a larger image and return me it's position. I want to set a tolerance threshold so that even if a similar (but not exactly the same) is present, it returns it's position as well.

If possible I would also want it to work if the smaller image is rotated.

I tried finding edges in the image using OpenCV, but the edges in the haystack and those in the needle image are never the *exact* same and it never matches.

```
public Point? Find(Bitmap haystack, Bitmap needle)
{
    if (null == haystack || null == needle)
    {
        return null;
    }
    if (haystack.Width < needle.Width || haystack.Height < needle.Height)
    {
        return null;
    }

    var haystackArray = GetPixelArray(haystack);
    var needleArray = GetPixelArray(needle);

    foreach (var firstLineMatchPoint in FindMatch(haystackArray.Take(haystack.Height - needle.Height), needleArray[0]))
    {
        if (IsNeedlePresentAtLocation(haystackArray, needleArray, firstLineMatchPoint, 1))
        {
            return firstLineMatchPoint;
        }
    }

    return null;
}

private int[][] GetPixelArray(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    var result = new int[bitmap.Height][];
    var bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly,
        PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

    for (int y = 0; y < bitmap.Height; ++y)
    {
        result[y] = new int[bitmap.Width];
        Marshal.Copy(bitmapData.Scan0 + y*bitmapData.Stride, result[y], 0, result[y].Length);
    }

    bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);

    return result;
}

private IEnumerable<Point> FindMatch(IEnumerable<int[]> haystackLines, int[] needleLine)
{
    var y = 0;
    foreach (var haystackLine in haystackLines)
    {
        for (int x = 0, n = haystackLine.Length - needleLine.Length; x < n; ++x)
        {
            if (ContainSameElements(haystackLine, x, needleLine, 0, needleLine.Length))
            {
                yield return new Point(x, y);
            }
        }
        y += 1;
    }
}

private bool ContainSameElements(int[] first, int firstStart, int[] second, int secondStart, int length)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    {
        if (first[i + firstStart] != second[i + secondStart])
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

private bool IsNeedlePresentAtLocation(int[][] haystack, int[][] needle, Point point, int alreadyVerified)
{
    //we already know that "alreadyVerified" lines already match, so skip them
    for (int y = alreadyVerified; y < needle.Length; ++y)
    {
        if ( ! ContainSameElements(haystack[y + point.Y], point.X, needle[y], 0, needle.Length))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

For the first: You have to define your metric for comparing two pixels

I can imagine a distance in the cube defined by RGB, or a distance in the cylinder of HSV (HSV should be more accurate)
Example:

```cs
        static double GetMetric(Pixel a, Pixel b)
        {
            double dR = a.R - b.R;
            double dG = a.G - b.G;
            double dB = a.B - b.B;

            return Math.Sqrt(dR * dR + dG * dG + dB * dB);
        }
```

Then just create a window search algorithm. Create window in the haste (same size as needle). Then try every possible position of window and calculate window distance as the sum of pixel distances.

You do not recalculate whole window. While moving window to the right, just recalculate and subtract left column (the one which was removed) and calculate and add right (new) column.

Then you need to remember minimal distance and its location and just compare it.

The result is the closest window to the needle. (Depends on used metric).

A simplified example:

```cs
        static void Find(Bitmap Haste, Bitmap Needle)
        {
            //Simplified for Haste.Height = Needle.Height
            //But Haste.Width > Needle.Width

            int minX = 0;
            int minY = 0;
            double minMetric = double.MaxValue;

            //Setup first window
            double actualMetric = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < Needle.Width; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < Needle.Height; j++)
                {
                    actualMetric += GetMatric(Needle.GetPixel(i, j), Haste.GetPixel(i, j));
                }
            }
            minMetric = actualMetric;


            //Move window to the right
            for (int i = 0; i < Haste.Width - Needle.Width; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < Needle.Height; j++)
                {
                    //Subtract left column pixel
                    actualMetric -= GetMatric(Needle.GetPixel(i, j), Haste.GetPixel(i, j));

                    //Add right column pixel
                    actualMetric += GetMatric(Needle.GetPixel(i + Needle.Width, j), Haste.GetPixel(i + Needle.Width, j));
                }

                //Compare
                if(actualMetric < minMetric)
                {
                    minX = i;
                    minY = 0; // Because Y is fixed while simplification Haste and Needle Height
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: But this won't work for grayscale images. And this would also match many different images having similar color ratios

Comment: And how can I use this with rgb? An example ?

Comment: @mrid This exactly findes smalle rimage int the bigger one. It finds the closest window (smaller image) int the haste.

Comment: Can you please provide an example of how to use this?

Comment: It's used to analyse handwritten number or letters (for example handwritten 3 is by metric close to integer 3 and also to integer 8, you never can get 100% match from metric)

Comment: There is a simplified example: